# query to count number of unique relations

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 tables:
    t_user (id, name)
    t_user_deal (id, user_id, deal_id)
    t_deal (id, title)

multiple user can be linked to the same deal. (I'm using oracle but it should be similar, I can adapt it)

How can I get all the users (name) with the number of unique user he made a deal with.

let's explain with some data:

```
t_user:
id, name
1, joe
2, mike
3, John

t_deal:
id, title
1, deal number 1
2, deal number 2

t_user_deal:
id, user_id, deal_id
1, 1, 1
2, 2, 1
3, 1, 2
4, 3, 2
```

the result I expect:
    user_name, number of unique user he made a deal with
    Joe, 2
    Mike, 1
    John, 1

I've try this but I didn't get the expected result:

```
SELECT tu.name,
    count(tu.id) AS nbRelations
FROM t_user tu
INNER JOIN t_user_deal tud ON tu.id = tud.user_id 
INNER JOIN t_deal td ON tud.deal_id = td.id 
WHERE 
(
    td.id IN 
    (
      SELECT DISTINCT td.id 
      FROM t_user_deal tud2 
      INNER JOIN t_deal td2 ON tud2.deal_id = td2.id 
      WHERE tud.id <> tud2.user_id
    )
) 
GROUP BY tu.id
ORDER BY nbRelations DESC
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you the result

```
     SELECT id1, count(id2),name
     FROM ( 
            SELECT distinct tud1.user_id id1 , tud2.user_id id2
            FROM t_user_deal tud1, t_user_deal tud2 
            WHERE tud1.deal_id = tud2.deal_id
            and tud1.user_id <> tud2.user_id) as tab, t_user tu
     WHERE tu.id = id1 
     GROUP BY id1,name
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
select name, NVL (i.ud, 0) ud from t_user join (
SELECT user_id, count(*) ud from t_user_deal group by user_id) i on on t_user.id = i.user_id
where i.ud > 0
```

Unless I'm missing somethig here.  It actually sounds like your question references having a second user in the t_user_deal table.  The model you've described here doesn't include that.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL example:

```
create table t_user (id int, name varchar(255)) ;
create table t_deal (id int, title varchar(255)) ;
create table t_user_deal (id int, user_id int, deal_id int) ;

insert into t_user values (1, 'joe'), (2, 'mike'), (3, 'john') ;
insert into t_deal values (1, 'deal 1'), (2, 'deal 2') ;
insert into t_user_deal values (1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 1), (3, 1, 2), (4, 3, 2) ;
```

And the query.....

```
SELECT
  name, COUNT(DISTINCT deal_id)
FROM
  t_user INNER JOIN t_user_deal ON (t_user.id = t_user_deal.user_id)
GROUP BY
  user_id, name ;
```

The DISTINCT might not be necessary (in the COUNT(), that is).  Depends on how clean your data is (e.g., no duplicate rows!)

Here's the result in PostgreSQL:

```
 name | count 
------+-------
 joe  |     2
 mike |     1
 john |     1
(3 rows)
```